# Predicate push down not working for full outer join in Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Predicate push down does not seem to be happening for Full outer join in Spark Dataframe

It seems that predicate push down works when the join type is inner. but when it is fullouter it does not push down the predicates

```
scala> val left = Seq((0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c")).toDF("id", "val")
2019-07-03 13:46:40 WARN  ObjectStore:568 - Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
left: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, val: string]

scala> val right = Seq ((2, "c"), (3, "d")).toDF("id", "val_2")
right: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, val_2: string]

scala> val df = left.join(right, Seq("id"), "fullouter")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, val: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+---+----+-----+
| id| val|val_2|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   b| null|
|  3|null|    d|
|  2|   c|    c|
|  0|   a| null|
+---+----+-----+


scala> val df = left.join(right, Seq("id"), "fullouter").where($"id" === 1)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: int, val: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Project [coalesce(id#5, id#14) AS id#33, val#6, val_2#15]
+- *(3) Filter (coalesce(id#5, id#14) = 1)
   +- SortMergeJoin [id#5], [id#14], FullOuter
      :- *(1) Sort [id#5 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#5, 200)
      :     +- LocalTableScan [id#5, val#6]
      +- *(2) Sort [id#14 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#14, 200)
            +- LocalTableScan [id#14, val_2#15]

scala> val df = left.join(right, Seq("id"), "inner").where($"id" === 1)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: int, val: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#5, val#6, val_2#15]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#5], [id#14], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Project [_1#2 AS id#5, _2#3 AS val#6]
   :  +- *(2) Filter (_1#2 = 1)
   :     +- LocalTableScan [_1#2, _2#3]
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)))
      +- *(1) Project [_1#11 AS id#14, _2#12 AS val_2#15]
         +- *(1) Filter (_1#11 = 1)
            +- LocalTableScan [_1#11, _2#12]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can push down predicates in inner join because the results is same.
But, if you push down predicates in full outer join, it will get different result (compare to the one who don't push down predicates).
So, in full outer join, predicates can't push down.
You will find the same thing in mysql or postgresql.